# insert into statement using @synTarget

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am current using SQL Server 2008 R2

```
DECLARE @synName VARCHAR(100), @synTarget VARCHAR(150), @synSchemaName VARCHAR (110)

DECLARE Syns CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FOR
   SELECT 
      s.name, base_object_name, sc.name AS synSchemaName
   FROM 
      sys.synonyms s
   INNER JOIN 
      sys.schemas sc ON s.schema_id = sc.schema_id
   WHERE 
      s.name in ('bunt') 

OPEN Syns

FETCH NEXT FROM Syns INTO @synName, @synTarget, @synSchemaName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'DROP SYNONYM guest.' + @synName

    EXEC ('DROP SYNONYM guest.' + @synName) 

    SET @synTarget = CASE 
                        WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%ChardCake2%' 
                          THEN REPLACE(@synTarget, 'ChardCake2', 'ChardCake3')
                        WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%ChardCake3%' 
                          THEN REPLACE(@synTarget, 'ChardCake3', 'ChardCake4')
                        WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%ChardCake4%' 
                          THEN REPLACE(@synTarget, 'ChardCake4', 'ChardCake2')
                     END

    PRINT 'CREATE SYNONYM guest.' + @synName + ' FOR ' + @synTarget
    EXEC ('CREATE SYNONYM guest.' + @synName + ' FOR ' + @synTarget) 

    PRINT 'TRUNCATE TABLE'+@syntarget
    EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE'+@syntarget)

    FETCH NEXT FROM Syns INTO @synName, @synTarget, @synSchemaName

    INSERT INTO ChardCake3 
        SELECT * 
        FROM ChardCake2
END

CLOSE Syns
DEALLOCATE Syns
```

The above query is being used to automatically drop and create synonyms in my database. The one issue I am running into is I have hard coded the insert into statement and I am trying to avoid doing that.

I have tried using

```
INSERT INTO @synTarget 
    SELECT * FROM ChardCake''
```

and it doesn't show that anything happened and that '' is not a correct syntax.

I have also tried adding

```
SET @newSynTarget = CASE 
                       WHEN @newSynTarget LIKE '%ChardCake2%' 
                          THEN REPLACE(@curSynTarget, 'ChardCake2', 'ChardCake4')
                       WHEN @newSynTarget LIKE '%ChardCake3%' 
                          THEN REPLACE(@curSynTarget, 'ChardCake3', 'ChardCake2')
                       WHEN @newSynTarget LIKE '%ChardCake4%' 
                          THEN REPLACE(@curSynTarget, 'ChardCake4', 'ChardCake3')
                    END
```

and

```
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + quotename(@newSynTarget) + 
              ' SELECT * FROM ' + quotename(@curSynTarget)`
```

when I run this also in the query after the table has truncated it shows as if nothing was there.

I haven't been able to figure out how to get the

```
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + quotename(@newSynTarget) + 
              ' SELECT * FROM ' + quotename(@curSynTarget)
```

to actually be seen in the query and function. is there anything else that I need to do to get this to work.

Original ^

```
    use TestingT1
go

DECLARE @synName VARCHAR(100), @synTarget VARCHAR(150), @synSchemaName VARCHAR (110)

DECLARE Syns CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FOR
SELECT s.name, base_object_name, sc.name AS synSchemaName
 FROM sys.synonyms s
   INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
     ON s.schema_id = sc.schema_id
  where s.name in ('bunt') 
OPEN Syns
FETCH NEXT FROM Syns INTO @synName, @synTarget, @synSchemaName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
PRINT 'DROP SYNONYM guest.' + @synName
EXEC ('DROP SYNONYM guest.' + @synName) 
SET @synTarget = CASE 
                        WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%ChardCake2%' THEN REPLACE(@synTarget,'ChardCake2','ChardCake3')
                        WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%ChardCake3%' THEN REPLACE(@synTarget,'ChardCake3','ChardCake4')
                        WHEN @synTarget LIKE '%ChardCake4%' THEN REPLACE(@synTarget,'ChardCake4','ChardCake2')
           END
PRINT 'CREATE SYNONYM guest.' + @synName + ' FOR ' +@synTarget
EXEC ('CREATE SYNONYM guest.' + @synName + ' FOR ' +@synTarget)
PRINT 'TRUNCATE TABLE'+@syntarget
EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE'+@syntarget)
FETCH NEXT FROM Syns INTO @synName, @synTarget, @synSchemaName
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000), @newSynTarget varchar(20), @curSynTarget varchar(20) select @sql = '', @newSynTarget = 'newSynTarget', @curSynTarget = 'currentSynTarget'
SET @newSynTarget = CASE 
                       WHEN @newSynTarget LIKE '%ChardCake2%' THEN REPLACE(@curSynTarget, 'ChardCake2', 'ChardCake4')
                       WHEN @newSynTarget LIKE '%ChardCake3%' THEN REPLACE(@curSynTarget, 'ChardCake3', 'ChardCake2')
                       WHEN @newSynTarget LIKE '%ChardCake4%' THEN REPLACE(@curSynTarget, 'ChardCake4', 'ChardCake3')
                    END
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + quotename(@newSynTarget) + ' SELECT * FROM ' + quotename(@curSynTarget) EXEC (@sql)
END
CLOSE Syns
DEALLOCATE Syns
```

I have added the additional information into the query but the results are still the same as before nothing happens when i run the command and the previous table information doesn't insert into the the current table the synonym is pointing to.

For example my current synonym is pointing to ChardCake2 and once I run the Query it now points to ChardCake3 and clears out the table.

currently the table has information in it before the synonym is changed to point at 3

```
testcolumn  testcolumns testing
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
1   2   3
```

once the commands are ran this is what the table looks like

testcolumn  testcolumns testing

the previous table has information in it and nothing was moved over to the current table.

Comment: Please post your RDBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server 2008R2, etc.)

Comment: Looks like you missed "INTO". Example .. `declare @sql varchar(2000), @newSynTarget varchar(20), @curSynTarget varchar(20)
select @sql = '', @newSynTarget = 'newSynTarget', @curSynTarget = 'currentSynTarget'
SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + quotename(@newSynTarget) + ' SELECT * FROM ' + quotename(@curSynTarget)
EXEC (@sql)
`

Comment: i have made the changes in the script and added `INTO` with the `INSERT` it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to execute after constructing the insert statement.. `SELECT @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + quotename(@newSynTarget) + 
              ' SELECT * FROM ' + quotename(@curSynTarget)      EXEC (@sql)`.  If you get an error, then post the error.